# wxpython set Focus to wx.Menubar by pressing a key

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have a wx.menubar in my application, and I want to set focus to it by pressing a key, for example, "alt+o", and have as a result this:

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible? or if an event in wxpython to do it exists. Thank you. P.D: I have tried to use the SetFocus () method which extends from wx.Window but it doesn't work

Comment: Pressing the `Alt` key already focuses the MenuBar. Why do you want another way to achieve the same end?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony The problem is that I am using the wx.stc.StyledText component and the `Alt` does not work as it is shown in the image.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Sorry, it was mistake not to share from where I was trying to access to the wx.MenuBar

Comment: Take a look at `wx.stc.StyledText.CmdKeyAssign()` or start digging into the Scintiila API.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony okay, thank you. I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

You could use [accelerators](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2017/09/28/wxpython-all-about-accelerators/)

For example:

```
# ... 
# Menu Bar
self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
file_menu = wx.Menu()
item = file_menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Salir", "")
self.menubar.Append(file_menu, "Archiv&o")
self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)
#...
```

You should be able to select the "Archivo" menu using "Alt + o".

Comment: It works, but I want to send it the focus from a wx.stc.StyledText as I use in others components with `Alt`, sorry for not saying it was a wx.stc.StyledText component